# cross-compiling with gcc, got storage size of ... isn't known error when it is defined in an include file under sysroot

Tags: gcc, busybox

I have a question very simliar to [Cross compiler default include path setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514098/cross-compiler-default-include-path-setup) but there wasn't the answer I was looking for.

I built a cross-compiler for openrisc. I have it in ~/openrisck/toolchain/
under there, I have bin(or32-linux-* excutables are here), include, lib, lib64, libexec, or32-linux, share.
under or32-linux, I have bin, include, lib, sys-root.

When I build busybox, I gave CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILER_PREFIX as "or32-linux-".
and CONFIG_SYSROOT as "$SYSROOT" which is ~/openrisk/toolchain/or32-linux/sys-root.

then I run 'make install' in buxybox source. Since the path includes the cross-compiler directory, it compiles for or32-linux-. But I have an error below

```
ckim : srctree = /home/ckim/openrisc/busybox
  CC      applets/applets.o
In file included from /home/ckim/openrisc/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/or32-linux/4.5.1-or32-1.0rc1/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                 from /home/ckim/openrisc/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/or32-linux/4.5.1-or32-1.0rc1/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from include/platform.h:141,
                 from include/libbb.h:13,
                 from include/busybox.h:8,
                 from applets/applets.c:9:
/home/ckim/openrisc/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/or32-linux/4.5.1-or32-1.0rc1/include-fixed/limits.h:169:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [applets/applets.o] Error 1
make: *** [applets_dir] Error 2
```

which makes me thinks that Ah! the cross-compiler uses the include path relative to the executable. (see above bin/../lib/gcc/or32-linux/version/include-fixed)

So the include limits.h goes to the gcc's limits.h correctly. The last file syslimits.h has #include_next  when the limits.h file have already been included. and the compiler complains that the file cannot be found.
Can somebody tell me how to solve this problem? (limits.h includes syslimits.h and syslimits.h includes limits.h .. )

EDIT : I ran 'make CROSS_COMPILE=or32-linux- CONFIG_PREFIX=$SYSROOT install'
then I got 'lutimes undeclared in coreutil/touch.c' error. Assuming the limit.h problem is gone, this means I should give these command line arguments because CROSS_COMPILE for make is different from CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILER_PREFIX in busybox configuration and make's CONFIG_PREFIX is different from CONFIG_SYSROOT for busybox configuration. so to remove the lutimes error, I ran 'make menuconfig' and removed CONFIG_TOUCH. Then I reran the make(make CROSS_COMPILE=or32-linux- CONFIG_PREFIX=$SYSROOT install), and this time got

```
procps/free.c: In function 'free_main':
procps/free.c:51:17: error: storage size of 'info' isn't known
procps/free.c:77:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sysinfo'
```

I found that in $SYSROOT/usr/include/sys/sysinfo.h, struct sysinfo is defined. I don't know why it says it's not defined. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be facing the same problem I had..
I tried about 3 times with the old toolchain but failed.
Yesterday, I got help from IRC (openrisc) and someone told me there is an updated toolchain for or1k. (not or32 which is old. I should have read the opencore page first..)
The page is
http://opencores.org/or1k/OpenRISC_GNU_tool_chain#Linux_.28uClibc.29_toolchain_.28or1k-linux-uclibc.29   (read from Linux (uClibc) toolchain (or1k-linux-uclibc))